# In Experience Profile - there is no row at position 0 error

Tags: experience-profile

In Sitecore 8.1-3 whenever I go in to the Experience Profile and select a contact and view either the Overview tab or the Profiling tab I see the following error on the screen: "There is no row at position 0".  What does this mean?

I found this posting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783328/sitecore-8-revision-150121-analytics-mongodb-error-there-is-no-row-at-pos - but that is not really helpful.  It seems to say that this is just a coding bug. Does that mean it can safely be ignored?

EDIT: adding log info

When I look in the Sitecore logs I see the following:

```
3836 14:13:51 INFO  Experience Profile view profile-pattern-matches called
3836 14:13:51 ERROR There is no row at position 0.
Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Message: There is no row at position 0.
Source: System.Data
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex)
   at System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Processors.FindBestPatternMatchAndApplyToProfileInfo.ApplyPatternToOneProfile(ReportProcessorArgs args, DataRow profileRow)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Processors.FindBestPatternMatchAndApplyToProfileInfo.ApplyPatternsToResultTable(ReportProcessorArgs args, DataTable resultTable)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.PipelineViewProvider.GenerateContactView(ViewParameters viewParameters)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.IntelController.Get(ViewParameters viewParams, Guid contactId, String viewId, String id)
```

Comment: What have you done so far to debug/research the issue? Anything in the logs?

Comment: Added log info to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because there are no pattern and profile cards.

It is fixed in the 8.2 Initial release (release notes):

> Experience Profile    The error: "There is no row at position 0" appears
>   in the Experience Profile for contacts with personal info and when
>   there are no pattern cards.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes

As a workaround, you can just add one pattern and profile card

Answer (score 2):

I believe I figured out the problem.  We had not set up any Profile Cards or Pattern Cards.  And so I think the system was displaying that error because it was expecting to find Profile or Pattern Cards.  Once I added a Profile Card and a Pattern Card the error went away.